# Cocoapods project settings issues

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I seem to have a issue with my project settings, in Xcode 8. The issue is as follows:

When adding a new `Pod` - lets say, `Pod Firebase` - the install works, and adds the necessary files to my project. I can then, do `@Import Firebase`

All is fine, up to this point. However, as soon as I make a reference to the `Firebase` API example: `[FirApp configure];` - all is still fine - autocomplete on Xcode works as expected and no issues. However, when building I then get a compile time issue which states:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAppIndexing", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The only way I am able to solve this - is by manually adding the `_FIRAppIndexing.framework` in my projects, Build settings, under `Link Libraries with Libraries`

To do that, I just drag and drop the frame work from the project navigator to the correct section under link libraries.

This works sometimes; as with other parts of the Firebase SDK, I get runtime crashes.

So, to try get to the root cause, I created a brand new test project, installed the Pods using `Pod install` - I however did not have to add the `framework` manually to Libraries - its actually not even listed there.

Everything in the test project worked just fine, at compile and run time.

Which leads me to believe its something in my project settings that's causing this.

**Things I have tried**

- Removed cocoapods completely with `pod deintegrate` and removed all
  other traces of it. Then did a clean build. Then `Pod install`
- Added -objc to linker flag

**Podfile**

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
    # platform :ios, '9.0'

    target 'MyApp' do
      # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
       use_frameworks!

      # Pods for MyApp
        pod 'Crashlytics'
        pod 'AsyncDisplayKit', '>= 2.0'
        pod 'Firebase'
        pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
        pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
        pod "HockeySDK", :subspecs => ['AllFeaturesLib']
        pod 'Fabric'
        pod 'FirebaseAppIndexing'
        pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
        pod '1PasswordExtension', '~> 1.8.4'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

  end

end
```

**GitHub example project**

https://github.com/TanderZA/MyApp

I duplicated my current project - and removed all files. Problem still exists. You will see the project won't compile due to linker errors, with references to the Firebase AP. 
By manually adding the frameworks to Link Libraries with Libraries, you will see that it should compile. But that is not how it should work. The current project has an issue with infoPlist.strings that I did not solve. But the project is in the state to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: May you please give me your xcode clang number?

Comment: Are you building for release or debug? Also, can you check the 'Build Active Architecture Only' settings on your Application target?

Comment: @Zich Xcode version is: 8.2.1 (8C1002) 
Sirss- For debug. And I have tried with Build Active Architecture Only-on/off- but did not make a difference.

Comment: May I ask you to attach invocations traceback using -v switch? I need to make sure we are on the same page.

Comment: Sure, how do I do that exactly? (Just want to make sure you have exactly what you're asking for ) 
Thanks

Comment: can't you add any information regarding the crashes?

Comment: @hasan83 The crashes happen when I don't explicitly link certain frameworks. As I say, I shouldn't have to do this in a normal Cocopods environment.

Comment: can you please add you pod file? and how many targets do you have? and their names.

Comment: Added to question -  @hasan83 - only the one target "MyApp"

Comment: @Tander Can you share the code or git or anything which I can have hands on?

Comment: Sure, I'll need to duplicate my current project and then remove the sensitive stuff. Give me 30 mins @ParthAdroja

Comment: @Tander OK you can share me a link of git or zipped

Comment: @ParthAdroja Sorry for the delay. Please see edited question with the GitHub link o the project.

Comment: @Tander Let me check

Comment: @Tander Found the issue. Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the project, it seems you have messed up with schemes.

Create a new scheme properly then install the pods again and as the project is in Obj-C you don't need to enable frameworks in the podfile.

So comment like   `# use_frameworks!`

Also update the pods using `pod update`

Then select the new scheme and build the project in it.

Let me know if you are not able to do it.

Comment: Whilst I wasn't able to completely solve the problem, your suggestions got me much closer to solving it than I had before. I also understand how the Pods integrate more now into an Xcode project - I however don't believe it was something I did. I installed Cocoapods after the project was live for a while. As @Zich mentions, its possibly a bug. 

With a newer project, I did not have to mess around with any schemes or uncomment use frameworks! - things just worked. The only difference was that I integrated Pods from the get go. 

Thanks for the help, and time. Much appreciated.

Comment: No, it doesn't't work still. This was after deleting the schemes, re adding them and adding Pod Install. But I think it's more to do with other issues of old configurations in the Xcode project. The test project works now, as per your suggestions.

Comment: @Tander Yes the test project you gave was building successfully.

Comment: Correct - which solved the main issue, which is why I accepted this answer. I have since migrated the old Xcode project to a new one and have it running well with Cocoapods. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It is a xcode bug by the way

But try this :

1. Upgrade to latest version of xcode and Pods
2. Remove all architectures in your project
3. Clean your project
4. Add arcitectures from start.

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this. I removed all libraries that the project had.Then removed Pods completely. Reinstalled it all and clean project. Still the same issue. Running on latest released version of Xcode. But having tried the current BETA it made no difference

Comment: This is looking more and more like an Xcode bug. I have moved the project to a new Xcode project and painfully reset everything. So far, this is working now

Comment: @Tander I've seen a several bugs during my experience with xcode, was it your first time? I am just curious to know your experience with xcode cause it seemed to me you believed in xcode robustness and didn't accept this situation as a bug at first place.

Comment: Used Xcode for the last 4 years. I just don't know how this could be a bug on Xcode's side, rather than Cocoapods. But we learn I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use frameworks?

```
# platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
```

Comment: Yeah, I have, thanks. FWIW - if I remove that line, I get additional compiler time errors / warnings

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure though but I think what you need is pod `'Firebase/Core'`. not pod 'Firebase'.

[This link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available_pods) have the list of the Firebase framework that can be used.

And, in the video on the top of the page it says something about there is no single pod that can be installed and you need to set each one of them on the podfile depending on the features you want.

My guess they mislead us in some places where they had `pod 'Firebase'`. I dont think that they meant that it should do the work.

som try the following:

```
# Pods for MyApp
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    .
    .
```

I know that you said that you had it work on another new project.